# How to recover a tree structure from an unfavorable representation of one?

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say we have an unfavorable representation of a tree. This tree is not nested, but flattened and its nodes are "connected" only by ids:

```
{
   "nodes":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "value":"and",
         "children":[
            1,
            4
         ]
      }
      {
         "id":1,
         "value":"or",
         "children":[
            2,
            3
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "value":"or",
         "children":[
            5,
            6
         ]
      }
   ],
   "leafs":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "value":"some statement"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "value":"some statement"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "value":"some statement"
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "value":"some statement"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can see that the tree is not only flattened, there is also a rather unnecessary representation of the leafs as a dedicated list.
The ids of the leafs are therefore appearing twice: Once as a child in its parent node and once as an identifier of the leaf.

What I want is a nested representation of this tree as dedicated python objects. I have to substitute the "id" with the whole object and get rid of the overly complicated list representation.

This is what I want:

```
{
  "tree": {
    "id": 0,
    "value": "and",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "or",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "some statement"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "value": "some statement"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "value": "or",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "value": "some statement"
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "value": "some statement"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How would I start to parse the two lists, so that I can build python objects (node and leaf classes), that reference each other and are representing this tree structure just by reference.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, operator):
        self.id = id
        self.value= operator
        self.children = None

class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, id, operator):
        self.id = id
        self.value = None
```

These are my tree classes, but I don't know how to traverse the two list in a way that brings me to my desired tree.

Comment: I would browse the list a first time, to build a dict that maps each id to the corresponding object; and also to identify the roots (nodes that don't have parents). Then build your tree, starting from the roots, using the dict to quickly find the children.

Comment: what  is the difference between `Connector` and `Parameter` classes?

Comment: Connector class represents a node. Parameter class represents a leaf. I should have renamed them accordingly. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your tree data to the dictionary with `id` as the key and node_data as the value.

**Code:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, node_id: int, operator: str, children: Optional[list] = None):
        self.id = node_id
        self.value = operator
        self.children = children

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node(id={self.id}, value={self.value})'


def build_tree(start: int, nodes: dict):
    node_data = nodes[start]
    node = Node(node_data['id'], node_data['value'])
    if node_data.get('children'):
        node.children = [build_tree(child, nodes) for child in node_data.get('children')]
    return node


nodes = {node['id']: node for node in data['leafs']}
nodes.update({node['id']: node for node in data['nodes']})

root = build_tree(0, nodes)
```

In the code I have created a class `Node` that maintains all the values, for leaf nodes `children` parameter will be `None`.

**Update:**

If you are using `Node` class as pydantic model

```
class Node(BaseModel):
    id: int
    value: str
    children: Optional[List['Node']]

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {'tree': self.dict()}
```

In the above pydantic model, I have added `to_dict()` method that will return that dictionary representation of the tree

**Sample Output:**

```
{
    'tree': {
        'id': 0,
        'value': 'and',
        'children': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'value': 'or',
                'children': [
                    {'id': 2, 'value': 'some statement', 'children': None},
                    {'id': 3, 'value': 'some statement', 'children': None},
                ],
            },
            {
                'id': 4,
                'value': 'or',
                'children': [
                    {'id': 5, 'value': 'some statement', 'children': None},
                    {'id': 6, 'value': 'some statement', 'children': None},
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you. So you are creating a dictionary out of both the nodes and the leafs and then just traverse them all. That's actually a very good idea.

Comment: Do you know what the reason is that I am not able to build a dictionary from my leaf objects? I get the following error: TypeError: 'Leaf' object is not subscriptable

Comment: does your input data have objects other than dictionaries?

Comment: My objects are actually pydantic models. So they are classes that inherit from BaseModel. For example: class Node(BaseModel):
    id: int
    value: str
    children: List[int]   What would be the best way to put that into the nodes dictionary?

Comment: Are you trying to convert tree(node objects)to dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to convert these node objects to the dict that you named "nodes" in your snippet. Then I get this error. I guess I have to convert the objects to dicts first in order to add them as a value in the dict? Do you know how to do that?